# getting database table to show in dataGridView in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am building a powershell gui application that pulls info from a database table that I need to monitor. I am having an issue getting that data into the datagridview. I can do it manually so it shows at least one entry but I need it to show the full table results. This is my 1st powershell GUI project.

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient

Function ShowJobsInQueue()

{

## To connect by Service Name
$ora_server = "dm01-scan.campsys.com"
$ora_user = "appuser"
$ora_pass = "hillary"
$ora_servicename = "dbcamp1_svc.campsys.com"


## by ServiceName
$connection = new-object system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=$ora_server)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=$ora_servicename)));User Id=$ora_user;Password=$ora_pass;")

$connection.open()

$query = "SELECT * FROM ASYNCJOB WHERE TRUNC(START_DATE)= TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND job_type <>15 and STATUS in ('1','2') ORDER BY ASYNCJOB_ID DESC"

$list_set = new-object system.data.dataset
#$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
#$array.AddRange($list_table)
#$dataGridView.DataSource = $array 
$list_adapter = new-object system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter($query, $connection)
$list_adapter.Fill($list_set) | Out-Null
$list_table = new-object system.data.datatable
$list_table = $list_set.Tables[0]
$DBValues = $list_table

while($dataGridView.Rows.Count -lt $list_table.Count) {
    $dataGridView.Rows.Add() | Out-Null
}

for ($i=0;$i -lt $list_table.Count ;$i++) {
    $dataGridView.rows[$i].Cells[0].Value = $list_table[$i].Item("ASYNCJOB_ID")
}

$connection.close()
$form.refresh()

}


$OnLoadForm_UpdateGrid= 
{ 
   ShowJobsInQueue

} 

########################################

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Report Monitor"
$Form.TopMost = $true
$Form.minimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1024,750)
$Form.maximumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1024,750)

$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1024,570)
$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)


$buttonRefresh = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$buttonRefresh.Text = "Refresh"
$buttonRefresh.Width = 65
$buttonRefresh.Height = 35
$buttonRefresh.Add_Click({
       $Form.close()
})
$buttonRefresh.location = new-object system.drawing.point(338,600)
$buttonRefresh.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$Form.controls.Add($buttonRefresh)


$buttonExit = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$buttonExit.Text = "Exit"
$buttonExit.Width = 65
$buttonExit.Height = 35
$buttonExit.Add_Click({
      $Form.close()
})
$buttonExit.location = new-object system.drawing.point(500,600)
$buttonExit.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$Form.controls.Add($buttonExit)

#Create an unbound DataGridView by declaring a column count.
$dataGridView.ColumnCount = 6
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true

#Set the column header names.
$dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Row#"
$dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "ASYNCJOB_ID"
$dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "USER_ID"
$dataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "START_DATE"
$dataGridView.Columns[4].Name = "END_DATE"
$dataGridView.Columns[5].Name = "STATUS"



#$dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "Value1"
#$dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "Value2"
#$dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = "Value3"
#$dataGridView.Rows.Add();


#############################################################

$buttonOn = New-Object system.windows.Forms.RadioButton
$buttonOn.Text = "On"
$buttonOn.Width = 65
$buttonOn.Height = 35
$buttonOn.Add_Click({
# create function to turn on auto mode
      $Form.close()
})
$buttonOn.location = new-object system.drawing.point(920,600)
$buttonOn.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$Form.controls.Add($buttonOn)

## button off 

$buttonOff = New-Object system.windows.Forms.RadioButton
$buttonOff.Text = "Off"
$buttonOff.Width = 65
$buttonOff.Height = 35
$buttonOff.Add_Click({
      # create function to turn off auto mode
      $Form.close()
})
$buttonOff.location = new-object system.drawing.point(870,600)
$buttonOff.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$Form.controls.Add($buttonOff)

## end button off


#### auto mode label

$Automode = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$Automode.Text = "Auto Mode"
$Automode.Width = 25
$Automode.Height = 10
$Automode.AutoSize = $true
$Automode.location = new-object system.drawing.point(875,580)
$Automode.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$Form.controls.Add($Automode)

#### end label


#Add Form event 
$form.add_Load($OnLoadForm_UpdateGrid) 


[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
$Form.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you could do it:

```
$DBValues = "Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","Value6","Value7","Value8","Value9","Value10"
while($dataGridView.Rows.Count -lt $DBValues.Count) {
    $dataGridView.Rows.Add() | Out-Null
}

for ($i=0;$i -lt $DBValues.Count ;$i++) {
    $dataGridView.rows[$i].Cells[0].Value = $DBValues[$i]
}
```

In your case you should do something like that:

```
while($dataGridView.Rows.Count -lt $list_table.Rows.Count) {
$dataGridView.Rows.Add() | Out-Null
}

for ($i=0;$i -lt $list_table.Rows.Count ;$i++) {
    $dataGridView.rows[$i].Cells[0].Value = $list_table.Rows[$i].Item("ASYNCJOB_ID")
}
```

Comment: when I added this code and ran the application it did add 10 new rows with values 1-10. if I change value 2 to ASYNCJOB_ID it doesnt put in the actual value of that database cell it just puts that name in the cell on the screen.

Comment: You can not use my code 1 to 1 you need to adpt it. My DBValues is in your code the variable $list_table

Comment: got ya. still a little confused though I tried this but it didnt work

$DBValues = $list_table.Rows[0]

Comment: When I originally did it this way I get the results I need but not the the datagridview


foreach ($entry in $list_table) {

$entry.Item("ASYNCJOB_ID")

}

Comment: I updated the code, try it. When it doesen't work check the datatype of $list_table, what is it?

Comment: Ok I tried the new code and the grid is still blank, how do I check the datatype of $list_table? I apologize i'm still learning

Comment: $list_table.GetType() and what is $list_table[0].GetType()

Comment: its a DataTable - I updated the entire code above with the changes

Comment: I updated my answer. You should use `$list_table.Rows.Count` instead of `$list_table.Count`. In both, the while loop and the forloop

Comment: hmmm - now i am getting this error

Could not compare "0" to " ". Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32"."
At line:36 char:11
+ for ($i=0;$i -lt $list_table.Count ;$i++)

Comment: Like I wrote, should add the row in the while and in the for loop `$list_table.rows.Count`

Comment: nevermind I had to fix $list_table.Rows.Count - thanks!

Comment: thank you so much! learning a lot today. I just ran my application and now it returns data! So now I see data coming in for ASYNCJOB_ID, how would I now modify the code to show the other column data? looks like I may have to do this?

$dataGridView.rows[$i].Cells[1].Value = $list_table.Rows[$i].Item("USER_ID")

Comment: Yes you have to do it like you wrote

Comment: got it all working! one last question - I have a refresh button, if I wanted to add an action on that button to refresh the DB results, would this work? I would think using the same function I created the get the DB results would work just as well?

$buttonRefresh.Add_Click({
       ShowJobsInQueue
})